# how to verify whether the all months are listed for a year in a given date range

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-6.0

I have below class

```
public class DateGenerator
{
    public DateOnly GeneratedDate {get; set;}
}
```

and list of dateGenerators `List<DateGenerator> dateGenerators;` as below

I need to verify whether all months are present for a year within the given range. For example, I have given a listed range; I need to identify the years first, and then for that year, whether all months are listed or not.

Here I have the same years along with the months listed, so the above condition also applies for the same years.

For example, not all months are listed below for the year `2009` and I have duplicate data for `2011`. All months are not listed in the second set of the same data year, `2011`, so I need to identify this.

| Date (Month/Day/Year) |
| --- |
| 7/1/2009 |
| 8/1/2009 |
| 9/1/2009 |
| 10/1/2009 |
| 11/1/2009 |
| 12/1/2009 |
| 1/1/2010 |
| 2/1/2010 |
| 3/1/2010 |
| 4/1/2010 |
| 5/1/2010 |
| 6/1/2010 |
| 7/1/2010 |
| 8/1/2010 |
| 9/1/2010 |
| 10/1/2010 |
| 11/1/2010 |
| 12/1/2010 |
| 1/1/2011 |
| 2/1/2011 |
| 3/1/2011 |
| 4/1/2011 |
| 5/1/2011 |
| 6/1/2011 |
| 7/1/2011 |
| 8/1/2011 |
| 9/1/2011 |
| 10/1/2011 |
| 11/1/2011 |
| 12/1/2011 |
| 4/1/2011 |
| 5/1/2011 |
| 6/1/2011 |
| 7/1/2011 |
| 8/1/2011 |
| 9/1/2011 |

I can group by `GeneratedDate` and extract the year and compare, but I am unsure how to tackle the duplicate data. Could anyone please let me know how to approach the same to identify

Thanks in advance!!

Sample method:

```
public bool verifyCompleteMonthlySet(List<DateGenerator> dateGenerators)
{
      //Identify whether all months are present for a year in a 
      //given a list, and also identify if there is 
      //any duplicate set found for a year, and all months are present for that same year as well
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] - we currently have no idea what data you have in what data structures. Any answer is likely to require that code.

Comment: "Identify whether all months are present for a year" - which year? Every year returned by any of the generators? The question is still *really* unclear IMO. It's not even clear how the `DateGenerator` type is relevant here - would your question be fundamentally different if your method accepted a `List<DateOnly>` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With LINQ you can write:

```cs
bool allMonthsAreListed = dateGenerators
    .GroupBy(dg => dg.GeneratedDate.Year)
    .All(g => g.Count() % 12 == 0);
```

Explanation:

1. We group by year.
2. For each group get the month count.
3. If the month count is divisible by 12 (with no remainder), all the sets in this year are complete.

Note that this is not perfect, e.g. there could be two incomplete sets in the same year whose month count adds up to 12. We would need to have a way to identify the sets. Do you have a set id or the like?

Also, I am not sure what you mean by *"I need to identify this"*.

1. Do only need to know that some years or sets are not complete?
2. You you need to identify the years/sets?
3. Do you need to know the missing months?

---

Since we do not have a way to identify sets, things get a bit more complicated:

```cs
bool allMonthsAreListed = dateGenerators
    .Select(dg => dg.GeneratedDate)
    .GroupBy(d => d.Year)
    .All(
        g => g.Count() % 12 == 0 &&
        g.GroupBy(d => d.Month)
            .Select(g2 => g2.Count())
            .Distinct()
            .Count() == 1
    );
```

Explanation:

1. We extract the date from the DateGenerators.
2. We group by year.
3. We test whether the count of months per year is divisible by 12 and ...
4. ... that all months occur the same number of times. To do this, we:

   1. group by month
   2. get the count of each month group
   3. get the distinct number of counts for all the groups
   4. test if this number is 1.

Note that if we have one full set, each month occurs once, if we have two full sets, each month occurs twice, etc. If the first set is complete and the second set has only 11 months, the we have 11 times a count of 2 and one time a count of 1. I.e., the distinct number of counts is 2. This identifies an incomplete set.

---

Tested with

```cs
List<DateGenerator> dateGenerators = new();

// Year 2010 with one complete set
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    dateGenerators.Add(new() { GeneratedDate = new DateOnly(2010, i, 1) });
}

// Year 2011 with 12 months but from two incomplete sets
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { // Set 1: months 1 to 10
    dateGenerators.Add(new() { GeneratedDate = new DateOnly(2011, i, 1) });
}
for (int i = 5; i <= 6; i++) {  // Set 2: months 5 and 6
    dateGenerators.Add(new() { GeneratedDate = new DateOnly(2011, i, 1) });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I do not want to code that year `2011`. Is there any way to identify the same through the code

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a set id, and I have only that date property, and I have two incomplete sets in the same year.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I just need to know that every month is present in a year set and if there is a duplicate year set and need to identify whether that same year is also an incomplete set with in given range, and I just need a bool variable

Comment: @kumar425: If you'd provided sample code that showed all the inputs and the expected outputs, the confusion would have been avoided...

Comment: @JonSkeet, Sorry for confusing everyone. The input list I have already listed the question, and the output is I need a bool variable and code. I am trying to figure out the solution

Comment: @kumar425: You've shown a screenshot. That's a *long* way from providing sample code. We have no idea whether you have strings, `DateTime` values etc. You're effectively asking someone to implement a method - but you haven't provided the signature of that method, or any kind of test input/output. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for guidance on how to write a good question.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes, Thanks for the explanation with the suggestions; I will try all scenarios and will update the results here

Answer (score 1):

Also using `System.Linq.GroupBy` but then doing a forensic by removing from `all`.

[image: screenshot]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "Missing months";
    // Get an array of DateTime.
    var dates = inputData.Trim().Split(',').Select(_=>DateTime.Parse(_)).ToArray();
    foreach (var year in dates.GroupBy(_=>_.Year))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{year.Key}");
        var months = year.Select(_ => _.Month).Distinct().ToArray();
        if (months.Length == 12)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"All months present.");
        }
        else
        {
            var all = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
            foreach (var month in months)
            {
                all.Remove(month);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{year.Key} missing {string.Join(", ", all )}");
        }
        foreach (var dup in year.GroupBy(_ => _).Where(_ => _.Count() > 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Duplicate dates: {dup.Key.ToShortDateString()} ({dup.Count()})");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Where `inputData` uses the data set from your post:

```
const string inputData = @"
7/1/2009,
8/1/2009,
9/1/2009,
10/1/2009,
11/1/2009,
12/1/2009,
1/1/2010,
2/1/2010,
3/1/2010,
4/1/2010,
5/1/2010,
6/1/2010,
7/1/2010,
8/1/2010,
9/1/2010,
10/1/2010,
11/1/2010,
12/1/2010,
1/1/2011,
2/1/2011,
3/1/2011,
4/1/2011,
5/1/2011,
6/1/2011,
7/1/2011,
8/1/2011,
9/1/2011,
10/1/2011,
11/1/2011,
12/1/2011,
4/1/2011,
5/1/2011,
6/1/2011,
7/1/2011,
8/1/2011,
9/1/2011";
```

Comment: I need to verify the duplicates year sets also whether those sets are complete or not

Comment: The answer has been edited to reflect this.